# createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not creating a user on firebase if called from real device

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to learn about Firebase and kotlin. Below is the sample code to create a user on firebase. Below mentioned code creates a user if I run the following code on android emulator. But if I run the following code on real Android device then the following code does not create a user on firebase. Android device has access to internet.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    fun signup(){
        val email = "john.doe6@yahoo.com"
        val password = "1234567890"
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                Log.d("Signup",task.toString())
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("Signup", "createUserWithEmail:success")
                } else {
                    Log.d("Signup", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(
                        baseContext,
                        "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    ).show()
                }
            }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        auth = Firebase.auth
        signup()
    }
}
```

Following is the logcat output.

```
Creating user with john.doe6@yahoo.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
Connection attempt already in progress
Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
 tagSocket(80) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
Activity resumed, time: 24954722
Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
Connection attempt already in progress
Connection attempt already in progress
Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 21
Connection attempt already in progress
Activity paused, time: 24954743
Connected to remote service
Processing queued up service tasks: 6
Application going to the background
Application backgrounded at: timestamp_millis: 1686640215952
Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Auth"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you aren't trying to create the same user again?

Comment: I do not see any user created in firebase console. If I run the code on Android emulator user gets created which I delete before I run the same code on the real device(pixel4a and samsung galaxy.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to your firebase project in "**project setting**" page of your firebase console.

**Using Gradle's Signing Report**

You can get the SHA-1 of your signing certificate using the Gradle signingReport command:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

After executing the above command you will get the following output which includes SHA-1 certificate fingerprint

```
> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: ~/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: A5:88:41:04:8D:06:71:6D:FE:33:76:87:AC:AD:19:23
SHA1: A7:89:E5:05:C8:17:A1:22:EA:90:6E:A6:EA:A3:D4:8B:3A:30:AB:18
SHA-256: 05:A2:2C:35:EE:F2:51:23:72:4D:72:67:A5:6C:8C:58:22:2A:00:D6:DB:F6:45:D5:C1:82:D2:80:A4:69:A8:FE
Valid until: Wednesday, August 10, 2044
```

After adding it to your firebase project uninstall app from device and again install and check if it is working.

Let me know if you are facing some other issues or above solution not working

Comment: Thanks for responding.I have uninstalled the app and added SHA-1 and SHA-256 in the firebase project settings of the app. But still I do not see  user created in firebase. With emulator the code works fine. But I am facing this problem with real devices(Pixel 4a, samsung galaxy etc.).

Comment: What error you are getting while creating user on real devices?

Comment: While I was looking for the error I found, a user signup process succeded on the real device too. But the above-listed code took 3 mins to create a user from a real device. while same code from android emulator took less than 5  secs. My phone and laptop are connected to the same network.